# Internal SSD not detected whle on 'Try Linux'

Tags: nvidia, ssd, cuda, detect

Currently running a windows laptop but needed to perform some CUDA computation on the GPU which can only be done on Linux. I created the boot image on the USB as per the instructions on the Ubuntu website, however when I go ahead and click 'Try Ubuntu', it seems like my internal SSD in the laptop is not being detected.
[Screenshot of gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqGIt.png)
Any pointers on how to get ubuntu to detect it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post any screenshot ? if you start gparted the disk does not appear?

Comment: Keep this in mind. With windows 10 fast start options, disk is not closed on shutdown. It is sort of a suspend. So you need to disable fast start to do a proper shutdown and allow Ubuntu to mount it.

Comment: Just posted the screenshot in the question! Unfortunately no the disk does not appear

Comment: I see the image. is there another disk on the drop down upper right? The image is showing the booted Ubuntu drive.

Comment: Nope just the booted ubuntu drive there aswell

Comment: Do you have an intel optane memory installed?

Comment: Nope running a toshiba ssd and a SK Hynix memory (16gb)

Comment: Also just switched off the fast start in win10 but still facing the same issue with linux.. Very strange

Comment: Please open a terminal and do `lsblk;blkid` and post the results. After that please do a `sudo dmesg|grep -i error` and post its results too. Please post results code formatted in your original post.